# Angular 7 and Asp .Net Razor

Tags: asp.net-core, angular7

I have used before AngularJS with webforms in some projects at work. I'm starting to migrate everything to .Net Core Razor mixing MVC as well and I would like to use latest Angular for some client side to work with web Apis mostly.

I see there is new .Net Core Angular Template and that you can Angular Items to your Solution in razor template, but how can I actually just add latest angular version to my existing razor project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). See how to [configure](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) dependencies in `package.json`. In visual studio right click on solution -> `Add` -> `New Item...`

[image]

For latest angular add `@angular/core` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/core).